# What I am doing wrong with this semantic segmentation?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe, matcaffe

Now it is quite a long time (almost two months) that I was working on FCN32 for semantic segmentation of single channel images. I played around with different learning rates and even adding `BatchNormalization` layer. However, I was not successful to even see any output. I did not have any choice except to instantly ask for help here. I really do not know what I am doing wrong.

I am sending one image to the network as a batch.This the train-loss curve `LR=1e-9` and `lr_policy="fixed"`:
[image]

I increased the learning rate to `1e-4`(the following figure). It seems that loss is falling down, however, the learning curve is not acting normal. 
[image]

I reduced the layers of original FCN as follows:
(1) Conv64 – ReLU – Conv64 – ReLU – MaxPool

(2) Conv128 – ReLU – Conv128 – ReLU – MaxPool

(3) Conv256 – ReLU – Conv256 – ReLU – MaxPool

(4) Conv4096 – ReLU – Dropout0.5

(5) Conv4096 – ReLU – Dropout0.5

(6) Conv2

(7) Deconv32x – Crop

(8) SoftmaxWithLoss

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    mean_file: "/jjj/FCN32_mean.binaryproto"
  }

  data_param {
    source: "/jjj/train_lmdb/"
    batch_size: 1
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "label"
  type: "Data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  data_param {
    source: "/jjj/train_label_lmdb/"
    batch_size: 1
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  transform_param {
    mean_file: "/jjj/FCN32_mean.binaryproto"
  }
  data_param {
    source: "/jjj/val_lmdb/"
    batch_size: 1
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "label"
  type: "Data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  data_param {
    source: "/jjj/val_label_lmdb/"
    batch_size: 1
    backend: LMDB
  }
}

layer {
  name: "conv1_1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1_1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 64
    pad: 100
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1_1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv1_1"
  top: "conv1_1"
}
layer {
  name: "conv1_2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv1_1"
  top: "conv1_2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 64
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1_2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv1_2"
  top: "conv1_2"
}
layer {
  name: "pool1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv1_2"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv2_1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "conv2_1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 128
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu2_1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv2_1"
  top: "conv2_1"
}
layer {
  name: "conv2_2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv2_1"
  top: "conv2_2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 128
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu2_2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv2_2"
  top: "conv2_2"
}
layer {
  name: "pool2"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv2_2"
  top: "pool2"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv3_1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool2"
  top: "conv3_1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu3_1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv3_1"
  top: "conv3_1"
}
layer {
  name: "conv3_2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv3_1"
  top: "conv3_2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu3_2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv3_2"
  top: "conv3_2"
}
layer {
  name: "pool3"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv3_2"
  top: "pool3"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc6"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool3"
  top: "fc6"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 4096
    pad: 0
    kernel_size: 7
    stride: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu6"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc6"
}
layer {
  name: "drop6"
  type: "Dropout"
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc6"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc7"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc7"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 4096
    pad: 0
    kernel_size: 1
    stride: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu7"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc7"
}
layer {
  name: "drop7"
  type: "Dropout"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc7"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layer {
  name: "score_fr"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "score_fr"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 5 #21
    pad: 0
    kernel_size: 1
    weight_filler {
        type: "xavier"
    }   
    bias_filler {
        type: "constant"
     } 
  }
}
layer {
  name: "upscore"
  type: "Deconvolution"
  bottom: "score_fr"
  top: "upscore"
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 5 #21
    bias_term: false
    kernel_size: 64
    stride: 32
    group: 5 #2
    weight_filler: { 
         type: "bilinear" 
     }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "score"
  type: "Crop"
  bottom: "upscore"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "score"
  crop_param {
    axis: 2
    offset: 19
  }
}
layer {
  name: "accuracy"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "score"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracy"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
}

layer {
  name: "accuracy"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "score"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracy"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "score"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
  loss_param {
    ignore_label: 255
    normalize: true
  }
}
```

and this is the solver definition:

```
net: "train_val.prototxt"
#test_net: "val.prototxt"
test_iter: 736
# make test net, but don't invoke it from the solver itself
test_interval: 2000 #1000000
display: 50
average_loss: 50
lr_policy: "step" #"fixed"
stepsize: 2000  #+
gamma: 0.1  #+
# lr for unnormalized softmax
base_lr: 0.0001 
# high momentum
momentum: 0.99
# no gradient accumulation
iter_size: 1
max_iter: 10000
weight_decay: 0.0005
snapshot: 2000
snapshot_prefix: "snapshot/NET1"
test_initialization: false
solver_mode: GPU
```

At the beginning, the loss is starting to fall down, but again after some iterations, it is not showing good learning behavior:
[image]

I am a beginner in deep learning and `caffe`. I really do not understand why this happens. I really appreciate if those that have expertise, please have a look on the model definition and I will be very thankful if you help me.

Comment: Are you using pretrained weights to start, or are you training the network from scratch (random weights)?

Comment: I am training from scratch actually. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are training from scratch.

Reading the [FCN paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.06211#) will tell you that they always use networks that are pretrained on ImageNet, it will **NOT** work if you train it from scratch, it has to be finetuned from a pretrained network. The optimization problem if you train from random weights just doesn't converge.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. By referring to this [link](http://cs231n.github.io/transfer-learning/) in point number `4`, that is said "New dataset is large and very different from the original dataset. Since the dataset is very large, we may expect that we can afford to train a ConvNet from scratch.", and since my data is very different from the original dataset of pretrained model, what will happen?? I think I got confused. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What can I do? what is your suggestion? thanks a lot

Comment: @S.EB The easiest is to pretrain your network on a dataset, say ImageNet for image classification, then change part of the architecture and finetune it. If you can't do this, then don't use your own network architecture and just use a pretrained network like VGG/ResNet.